# can we forcibily place data in a specific cache

Tags: multithreading, memory, memory-management, operating-system, scheduling

I am trying to forcibly put data into a cache(either L1, L2 or L3). After that i will create two threads and perform some read/write operations by accessing data present in the cache and measure the performance of CPU based on the placement of data in cache. I will repeat the process by forcibly allocating the threads to different/same processor cores. How can this(forcibily place data in a specific cache) be done. BTW i am using intel xeon x5675 processor and linux